# Android FCM token without colon (:)

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I'm building a VoIP app, and I'd like to use FCM to be notified of incoming calls. The FCM token generated on Android contains a InstanceId prefix, followed by a colon (:). However, due to an implementation detail, I am unable to use string that contains colons. Is there a way to generate a valid token that doesn't contain a colon?

Specifically, I'm using [react-native-pjsip](https://github.com/datso/react-native-pjsip), and the library crashes when I pass the token in the contact params, since it contains a colon. It works when I wrap the string in double-quotes (" "), but my SIP provider doesn't support parsing these strings in quotes. So I'm trying to find a way to generate a token that will keep both sides happy, which is one that doesn't contain a colon.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API to control what tokens get generated by Firebase Cloud Messaging. So what you'll need to do is encode the token you get into a value that is valid for your infrastructure. For example, you could use a simple [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), which would turn a token `a:bc` into `a%3Abc`.